# Load JS from page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use `$('.class').load('url #id')`, but it get only html code, or I'm doing something wrong)

How get JS from page?

Site where I use this code: http://vbtes.p.ht/Amira/#!contacts (haven't js, don't work tabs).

Have JS: http://vbtes.p.ht/Amira/#!contacts

```
var sm = 1;
var oldactivemenu = 0;
var selectedmenu = '';
var elemthis;

function ocmenu(heshatr, thiselem) {
    elemthis = thiselem;
    if (sm == 1) {
        location.hash = '!' + heshatr;
    }
}
$(function () {
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
        // Alerts every time the hash changes!
        var linkmenuurl = $(location).attr('href').split("#!")[1];
        if (location.hash == '') {
            linkmenuurl = '';
        }
        if (sm == 1 && selectedmenu !== linkmenuurl) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(elemthis).addClass('active');
            if ($(elemthis).parent('.main-menu__item_level_1')) {
                $(elemthis).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-menu__item-link').addClass('active');
            }

            selectedmenu = linkmenuurl;
            sm = 0;
            $('.new').load(linkmenuurl + ' #lay_body_get', function () {
                $('.new').show();
                $('.lb2').css({
                    top: $('.lb1').height() * -1 - 60
                });
                $('.new').animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
                $('.old').animate({
                    left: -1450
                }, 500, function () {
                    $('.old').addClass('ob1');
                    $('.new').addClass('nw1');
                    $('.ob1').removeClass('old').addClass('new').css({
                        left: 1450
                    }).hide(100);
                    $('.nw1').removeClass('new').addClass('old').animate({
                        top: 0
                    }, 100, function () {
                        sm = 1;
                    });
                    $('.ob1').removeClass('ob1');
                    $('.nw1').removeClass('nw1');

                });
            });
        }
    })

    // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

Comment: Javascript needs to be inside a script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.getScript(url)` as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

If those are `<script>` tags inside the loaded HTML, iterate over them with jQuery, and load them using the function above.

**Addition:** You could do something like:

```
$.ajax(myPageURL, { complete: function (data) { 
    $(data.responseText).filter('script').each(function () { 
        $.getScript(this.src);

        // OR

        $('head').append($(this).html());
    }); 
}});
```

This is a workaround to the `jQuery.load()` issue. It loads the entire page again, but strips the `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>` (and etc.) element - thus allowing you to filter the scripts in the page's header. Note that this will cause the page to load a second time.

**BTW**, adding a `<script>` tag to your page instead of using `$.getScript()` enables debugging of the script in Chrome, at the very least.

Comment: Yes, those are <script>, can you say more, how use this?

Comment: Not using the `$.load` method. See what I wrote above.

Comment: I havent `src` in `<script>`, I have only structure in block #id `<script> Function(data){something}</script>` and I need copy this

Answer (score 3):

When you call .load using a selector, jQuery will strip the script from the result.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> **Script Execution**
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below: